# how to get values from first index of array in shell scripting?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have below code  and I want to get daily_balue, monthly_value, priorday_value, priorweek_value, priormonth_value from log file. As per the code the daily_value, monthly value, priorday value, prior week and priormonth value are stored in first index of array.

How to get daily,monthly value priority prior week and prior month values from first index of array ?

sql file as shown below:

first input file columns order:

```
cash , monthly_value, null,null, 0.000
cash, daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,3
cash, priormonth_value,2022-02-22,2022-02,8
cash , priorday_value, null,null, 10
cash, priorweek_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,32
loans, monthly_value, 2022-02-22,2022-02-22, 21.000
loans, daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,4
loans,priormonth_value,2022-02-22,2022-02,9
loans , priorday_value, null,null, 12
loans,priorweek_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,23
```

Output for first input should be stored in the below format in a csv file
format : $date, $row, $daily_balue, $monthly_value, $priorday_value, $priorweek_value, priormonth_value

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3, 0.00, 10, 32, 8
2022-02-22, loans, 4, 21.00, 12, 23, 9
```

In some case the priormonth_values might be missing, so need to add zero in the output file
second input file columns order:

```
cash , monthly_value, null,null, 0.000
cash, daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,3
cash , priorday_value, null,null, 10
cash, priorweek_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,32
loans, monthly_value, 2022-02-22,2022-02-22, 21.000
loans, daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,4
loans , priorday_value, null,null, 12
loans,priorweek_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,23
```

Output for second input should be stored in the below format in a csv file
format : $date, $row, $daily_balue, $monthly_vale, $priorday_value, $priorweek_value, priormonth_value

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3, 0.00, 10, 32, 0
2022-02-22, loans, 4, 21.00, 12, 23, 0
```

third input file columns order . here daily_value and monthly_value are missing from the file

```
cash, priormonth_value,2022-02-22,2022-02,8
cash , priorday_value, null,null, 10
cash, priorweek_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,32
loans,priormonth_value,2022-02-22,2022-02,9
loans , priorday_value, null,null, 12
loans, priorweek_value,2022-02-22, 2022-02-02,11
```

Output for third input should be stored in the below format in a csv file. daily_value and monthly_value are assigned 0
format : $date, $row, $daily_balue, $monthly_vale, $priorday_value, $priorweek_value, priormonth_value

```
2022-02-22, cash, 0, 0, 10, 32, 8
2022-02-22, loans, 0, 0, 12, 11, 9
```

```
declare -A arr


if [ -s $sqlfile ]
then 
  while IFS=, read key value; do
          arr[$key] = "${arr[$key]}$arr[$key]:+,}$value"
  done < $sqlfile

       i=0
       for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do
       row=`echo $key | xargs`
       values = ${arr[$key]}

       daily_value = `echo $values | cut -d ',' -f8 | xargs`
       priomonth_value = `echo $value | cut -d ',' -f12 | xargs`

       i = $((i+1))
       done
else
       echo "$sqlfile is empty"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: You have kinda sorta a CSV file. Do you really have variable spacing around the comma delimiters or not?

Comment: Sorry... no .csv file available to load.

Comment: @EdMorton, I have provided expected output files and their corresponding input files.

Comment: @ted Lyngmo ,The lines don't always start with cash.

Comment: Please read the description of tags you apply! Neither "linux" nor "shell" are good choices. Also, which shell are you using even?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I am using bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) (GNU's version of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)) to do this. The sporadic spaces around `,` in the input could be dealt with by using  `*, *` as the field separator (`FS`).

In some cases, there is `null` where the *date* should be, so I add the value in the `date` array with the value in the `null` array. Since only one of them is set, the sum will be the correct value.

This also solves the case if neither the `date` nor the `null` array contains a value. *blank* + *blank* becomes `0`.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=" *, *";
  OFS=", ";
}
{
  # [date][row][value_type] = value
  arr[$3][$1][$2] = $5;
}
END {
  cl[0] = "cash";
  cl[1] = "loans";
  for(date in arr) {
    if(date == "null") continue;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      row = cl[i];
      print date, row,
        arr[date][row]["daily_value"]     +arr["null"][row]["daily_value"],
        arr[date][row]["monthly_value"]   +arr["null"][row]["monthly_value"],
        arr[date][row]["priorday_value"]  +arr["null"][row]["priorday_value"],
        arr[date][row]["priorweek_value"] +arr["null"][row]["priorweek_value"],
        arr[date][row]["priormonth_value"]+arr["null"][row]["priormonth_value"];
    }
  }
}
```

###### Output

It's not exactly what you've listed as your expected output. When you expect `21.00`, it'll be just `21` here. If `.00` is important it can be fixed by using `printf("%.2f", the_value);` instead of just `print`ing the result of the addition above.

File 1:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3, 0, 10, 32, 8
2022-02-22, loans, 4, 21, 12, 23, 9
```

File 2:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3, 0, 10, 32, 0
2022-02-22, loans, 4, 21, 12, 23, 0
```

File 3:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 0, 0, 10, 32, 8
2022-02-22, loans, 0, 0, 12, 11, 9
```

---

---

A version with a scale of 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
  FS=" *, *";
}
{
  # [date][row][value_type] = value
  arr[$3][$1][$2] = $5;
}
END {
  cl[0] = "cash";
  cl[1] = "loans";
  vt[0] = "daily_value";
  vt[1] = "monthly_value";
  vt[2] = "priorday_value";
  vt[3] = "priorweek_value";
  vt[4] = "priormonth_value";
  for(date in arr) {
    if(date == "null") continue;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      row = cl[i];
      printf("%s, %s", date, row);
      for(j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        vtype=vt[j];
        printf(", %.2f", arr[date][row][vtype] + arr["null"][row][vtype]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

###### Output

File 1:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3.00, 0.00, 10.00, 32.00, 8.00
2022-02-22, loans, 4.00, 21.00, 12.00, 23.00, 9.00
```

File 2:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 3.00, 0.00, 10.00, 32.00, 0.00
2022-02-22, loans, 4.00, 21.00, 12.00, 23.00, 0.00
```

File 3:

```
2022-02-22, cash, 0.00, 0.00, 10.00, 32.00, 8.00
2022-02-22, loans, 0.00, 0.00, 12.00, 11.00, 9.00
```

Comment: I have edited the files and expected output.  Thanks

Comment: @blackhole I've updated the output part of my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ head file{1..3}
==> file1 <==
cash , monthy_value, null,null, 0.000
cash,daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,3
cash,priormonth_value,20shelll22-02-22,2022-02,8

==> file2 <==
cash,priormonth_value,2022-02-22,2022-02,8
cash , monthy_value, null,null, 0.000
cash,daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,3

==> file3 <==
cash , monthy_value, null,null, 0.000
cash,daily_value,2022-02-22,2022-02-22,3
```

I personally would use a combination of `awk` and `Bash` like so:

```
for fn in file{1..3}; do 
    declare -A arr
    
    while read k v; do 
        arr["$k"]="$v"
    done <<< $(awk -F, -v keys='daily_value priormonth_value' '
    BEGIN{split(keys,tmp,"[ \t]+"); for (e in tmp) tgt[tmp[e]]}
    $2 in tgt {
        gsub(/\s*,\s*/,",")
        printf("%s %s\n",$2,$(NF))
    }' "$fn")
    echo "$fn"
    declare -p arr
    unset arr 
    echo 
done
```

Prints:

```
file1
declare -A arr=([daily_value]="3" [priormonth_value]="8" )

file2
declare -A arr=([daily_value]="3" [priormonth_value]="8" )

file3
declare -A arr=([daily_value]="3" )
```